# Trying to learn how to get user inputted data from a form in c# to display onto a label, Visual studio shows no errors but the labels wont update

Tags: c#, winforms

Im still new to c# so I'm Not entirely sure if my code is correct but i wanted to let users input data into a form and have it show up onto a label to the right of the form. Visual studio doesnt give me any errors with my code so im not sure what part of it is wrong. I have several different kinds of inputs, from regular text, a phone number, and radio buttons. I am using .net winforms to do all of my coding by the way. Below is a copy of my code.

```
        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != "")
            {
                errorProvider1.Clear();
                label1.Text = textBox1.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "Please Enter Text!");
            }

        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (maskedTextBox1.Text != "")
            {
                errorProvider1.Clear();
                label2.Text = maskedTextBox1.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(maskedTextBox1, "Please Enter Text!");
            }

        }

        private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (groupBox1.Text != "")
            {
                errorProvider1.Clear();
                label3.Text = groupBox1.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(groupBox1, "Please Enter Text!");
            }

        }

        private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (twoyear.Text != "")
            {
                errorProvider1.Clear();
                label4.Text = twoyear.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(twoyear, "Please Enter Text!");
            }

        }

        private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (fouryear.Text != "")
            {
                errorProvider1.Clear();
                label5.Text = fouryear.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(fouryear, "Please Enter Text!");
            }

        }

        private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
        {
            monthCalendar1.MaxSelectionCount = 1;
        }

        private void label6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Lab3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With the code shown you'll have to click on the labels to update their text. Is this the wanted behavior? Do you have any other code which updates for example label1.Text? Also, if the labels have an automatic size, it will be hard to click them when their text property is an empty string, because they will have a very small width.

Comment: So, a User enters text in a TextBox and you want to show the same text in a Label? Is this what you want to do? Then, what will you do with the input? -- What about the Text of a GroupBox? -- Try to explain a bit better what is the intended outcome when a User enter values in different Control, you probably don't want to copy the same thing in another Control.

Comment: Your best friend, the [debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx), should help!

Answer (score 0):

To let the user input text, you just need to use this code:

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            //Show a message box (a little pop-up form with a message on it) to tell the user that they forgot to enter something into the textbox.
            //if you don't want the messagebox, just leave this section blank (delete 'messagebox.show("---"))

            MessageBox.Show("Oops, you forgot to enter something into the textbox - try again");
        }
        else //else are used to ask the computer, if the above if statement is not true (so the textbox text doesn't equal "")
        {
            label1.Text = textBox1.Text;
        }
    }
```

for the radio button use this code:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            //Show a message box (a little pop-up form with a message on it) to tell the user that they forgot to enter something into the textbox.
            //if you don't want the messagebox, just leave this section blank (delete 'messagebox.show("---"))

            MessageBox.Show("Oops, you forgot to enter something into the textbox - try again");
        }
        else //else are used to ask the computer, if the above if statement is not true (so the textbox text doesn't equal "")
        {
            label1.Text = textBox1.Text;

            //change label1 to whatever's text you want to change (radioButton1, textBox1, button1, etc.)
        }
    }
```